My background image is squished in the top-left corner of the webpage
My background Image is shrinked in a corner, even though my css, or html doesnt have any shrinking in it.
the background (https://thealphaleopard.github.io/home/)
my css:
.background-image {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: url('imgs/background.png');
    background: center no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    z-index: -1;
}

I have tried changing the css size and position, but none have helped.

The image is not in your imgs folder. In any case why not just use background-image on the body?

It is in my imgs folder. I will try that thanks!

It didn't work after i added the background image to the body...

Do you want the image to be the background to the whole body or fixed in the viewport (the part the user can see)

This is your problem background: no-repeat center; it's overriding the background-image declaration

Use the individual properties rather than the background shorthand property.
.background-image {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url('imgs/background.png');
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    z-index: -1;
}

